# R Merge - Left join but to show all variables

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have 2 data frames like below.

```
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID_1 = c("A","1","2","3","B","1","2","3","C","1","2","3"))
DF_2 <- data.frame(ID_2 = c("A","B","C"))
```

I need to create another dataframe like below.

```
   ID_1 ID_2
1     A    A
2     1 <NA>
3     2 <NA>
4     3 <NA>
5     B    B
6     1 <NA>
7     2 <NA>
8     3 <NA>
9     C    C
10    1 <NA>
11    2 <NA>
12    3 <NA>
```

I am currently using this to achieve the result. But, I would like to stay away from sql as much as possible.

```
library(sqldf)
RESULT <- sqldf('select aa.ID_1, bb.ID_2
                from DF_1 aa left join DF_2 bb 
                on aa.ID_1 = bb.ID_2')
```

I have also tried using merge.

```
RESULT <- merge(DF_1, DF_2, by.x = "ID_1", by.y = "ID_2", all.x = TRUE)
```

But, I am getting this below which is missing `ID_2`.

```
      ID_1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     3
9     3
10    A
11    B
12    C
```

Comment: Try `DF_1$ID_2<-ifelse(DF_1$ID_1 %in% DF_2$ID_2,as.character(DF_1$ID_1),NA)`. You are not actually doing a merge; rather, it seems to me that you want another column which is equal to the first if the value appears in the second data frame and NA otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `DF_2` has only one column, so the column to do merge on. You could do this

```
merge(DF_1, cbind(DF_2, DF_2$ID_2), by.x = "ID_1", by.y = "ID_2", all.x = TRUE)

   # ID_1 DF_2$ID_2
# 1     1      <NA>
# 2     1      <NA>
# 3     1      <NA>
# 4     2      <NA>
# 5     2      <NA>
# 6     2      <NA>
# 7     3      <NA>
# 8     3      <NA>
# 9     3      <NA>
# 10    A         A
# 11    B         B
# 12    C         C
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match`

```
DF_1$ID_2 <- DF_2$ID_2[match(DF_1$ID_1, DF_2$ID_2)]
DF_1
#   ID_1 ID_2
#1     A    A
#2     1 <NA>
#3     2 <NA>
#4     3 <NA>
#5     B    B
#6     1 <NA>
#7     2 <NA>
#8     3 <NA>
#9     C    C
#10    1 <NA>
#11    2 <NA>
#12    3 <NA>
```